# How to install Windows 7 in VirtualBox from Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: installation, drivers, windows, 13.04, virtualbox

Shortly after I installed Ubuntu 13.04, I installed VirtualBox in order to use Windows 7 in a virtual machine. When trying to install Windows I get the following:

> Cannot find a driver for the CD/DVD drive.
> If you have a CD, DVD or USB flash drive that could have the driver, insert it now.
>
> Note: if the installation media of Windows is in the CD or DVD drive, you can safely remove it to do this step.

My drive is named `HL-DT-ST DVD-RAM GH22NS30 (sr0)`.

[image: Screenshot]

<sup>Click on the image to open a full-resolution version</sup>